# How to detect an aborted connection with PHP PUT

Tags: php, upload, put, cancellation

I have written a PHP upload function which uses HTTP PUT, using XHR2 calls from the browser. Everything works great, but now I also need to detect if the user has cancelled the upload, closed the browser or if the network connection simply died.

And I have a very very hard time achieving this, up to the point where I begin to think its simply not possible, so any insights would be greatly appreciated!

The core of my upload code is actually nothing special and roughly looks like this:

```
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
$fp = fopen($tempPath, "a");
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024)) { fwrite($fp, $data); } 
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
```

First thought was to simply use the `register_shutdown_function`, but that function is not called until after about five minutes which is way to late. Also `connection_aborted`does not work. I really cannot output anything to the client while reading the data, not even a header or my response after that is failing with a "headers already sent" error. Now, it appears to me that the script is just waiting in the while loop for data that does not arrive anymore, twiddling thumbs.

So it seems I am totally stuck now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should check [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) with [connection_aborted](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php) or [connection_status](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-status.php).

Comment: Tried all of that stuff for hours now. And as I stated in my question I cannot use `connection_aborted` since I cannot output anything - not even a header! - to the client while receiving data without breaking the remaining script.